# Parsing Oracle Clob data to extract text between pattern

Tags: oracle, clob

1. I have data in below format in my oracle table.

```
        Column name         Data Type
        ID                  Int
        message_clob        clob

        Sample records in the table.
        1234,"{1:abced}{2:asdf}{4::20A:Toronto/123e4 //@,:32A:Montrea   
        l9999:52A:Quebec}
        2134,{1:ascbced}{2:as123df}{4::21A:Toront?//@,:57A:9999.999:72A:HAL 
    asfad}"
```

now my requirement is to load this data into a new table with below columns.

```
     Record1: 
        Column             Value
        ID                 1234 
        20A                Toronto/123e4 //@,
        21A                nULL
        32A                Montrea l9999
        52A                Quebec
        57A                nULL
        72A                nULL
        Record2:
        ID                 2134
        20A                nULL            
        21A                Toront?//@, 
        32A                nULL    
        52A                nULL    
        57A                9999.999    
        72A                HAL  asfad
```

I am trying using regular expressions but can't getting through the desired output. Can I get some assistance here.

Comment: Edit your post to fix the formatting - it's unreadable at this time.

Comment: Please show what you have you tried.

Comment: select  ID
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(message_clob,':20A:([[:alnum:]]+\S+)') as code20
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(message_clob,':21A:([[:alnum:]]+\S+)') as code21A
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(message_clob,':32A:([[:alnum:]]+\S+)') as code32A
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(message_clob,':52A:([[:alnum:]]+\S+)') as code52A 
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(message_clob,':57A:([[:alnum:]]+\S+)') as code57A
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(message_clob,':72A:([[:alnum:]]+\S+)') as code72A
from message_data;

Comment: Hi all any assistance on this. I am using regexp_instr to find the location and using substr to extract the values. But as the values are not constant in the clob data I am having difficulties. 
select id,substr(message_clob,regexp_instr(message_clob, ':50K:'),
(regexp_instr(message_clob, ':52D:')-regexp_instr(message_clob, ':50K:')))
from habs.habs_message